# How to fix a floating AWT Frame in Java for CDC?

Tags: java, awt, frame

I am designing an App for a `CDC` embedded device. I am using `java.awt.Frame` to display a for. I want this `Frame` to be fixed and not floating. Now my requirement is that the `Frame` should not be draggable. It should be fixed like desktop.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks and regards
Abhilasha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

non_rezizeable

[setResizable(boolean resizable)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setResizable%28boolean%29)

and un-draggable

[setUndecorated(boolean undecorated)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29)

Comment: Thank you for the response. :) I am already setting setResizable(false); So the problem is not with resizing.N coming to setUndecorated() for CDC apis donot have this method.

Comment: then implement java.awt.Window, because is by default undecorated :-)